# Unable to get a CSS3 animation to work when showing content through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create an expandable table that uses css3 animations when the table is expanded.  Essentially when you toggle details, we append a new row to the table.  This content has bars inside of it that should have a marker that animates left to right based on a width set in the bar marker data attribute. `<div class="marker" data-width="50"></div>`

Unfortunately I cannot get to animation to work on toggle.  Oddly enough, I can create a seperate button to "re-render" and it animates perfectly then.

Its hard to really explain any further then this so please check out the fiddle that demonstrates the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/vmef28df/21/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so as soon as the blue bars are visible you want them to start animating left and right?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot animate elements right after adding them to the DOM. Same happens if you have an element with `display: none;` and `opacity: 0;` and you want to animate it to `opacity: 1;`. What you have to do is to use either [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) or use a timeout.
I added the timeout to your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t364v5fb/2/)

Comment: My only concern is that I hate adding arbitrary timeouts.  I assume that this could mean a computer which is really slow, the 5 ms might not be enough?

Comment: I don't like using timeouts for such a case either. I think 5ms for a browser to add an element to the DOM should be long enough. If you are concerned about slow computers you should question your animation in general because on a slow computer it won't run smooth anyways. If slow equals <IE9 for you then you can add a test for csstransitions (e.g. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) ) and not run the timeout/animation in this case.